# How to make a method that will have affect on multiple variables?

Tags: java, arrays, class, for-loop, methods

I apologize if the question doesn't make sense. I made a bank account program that manages bank accounts and I was given an assignment that asks me to make a method that adds 3 percent interest to all bank accounts.

Here is the first part of the Account class:

```
public class Accounts
{
   private NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

   private final double RATE = 0.03;  // interest rate of 3.5%

   private int acctNumber;
   private double balance;
   private String name;
   //public Accounts[] account;

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Sets up the account by defining its owner, account number,
   //  and initial balance.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public Accounts (String owner, int account, double initial)
   {
  name = owner;
  acctNumber = account;
  balance = initial;


}
```

Here is the method on adding interest to a single account:

```
 public double addInterest ()
 {
      balance += (balance * RATE);
      return balance;
 }
```

Here is the method that I am working on to make multiple bank accounts gain interest:

```
public double addInterestAll ()

   for (int i = 0; i <= 29; i++){
       account[i].addInterestAll();
   }
   return balance;


}
```

The account variable above is an array that I made in the main method but because I declared the array in the main method, the compiler can't find it. I am not sure of another way for how I can make this work.

Here is the main method:

```
public class SixSix
{
public static void main (String []args)
{


Accounts[] account = new Accounts[30];

    account[0] = new Accounts ("Gerry Agam", 1, 1111.00);
    account[1] = new Accounts ("Jules Innes", 2, 2222.00);
    account[2] = new Accounts ("Shani Cahya", 3, 3333.00);
    account[3] = new Accounts ("Bao Shelly", 4, 4444.00);
    account[4] = new Accounts ("Sasha Ashley", 5, 5555.00);
    account[5] = new Accounts ("Özgür Mor", 6, 6666.00);
    account[6] = new Accounts ("Katlego Lashawn", 7, 7777.00);
    account[7] = new Accounts ("An Narcisse", 8, 8888.00);
    account[8] = new Accounts ("Amal Lalita", 9, 9999.00);
    account[9] = new Accounts ("Sabah Dalitso", 10, 1010.00);
    account[10] = new Accounts ("Charley Robin", 11, 1111.00);
    account[11] = new Accounts ("Jo Oluwasegun", 12, 1212.00);
    account[12] = new Accounts ("Vic Nithya", 13, 1313.00);
    account[13] = new Accounts ("Nuka Kirabo", 14, 1414.00);
    account[14] = new Accounts ("Madhu Munashe", 15, 1515.00);
    account[15] = new Accounts ("Saša Guanting", 16, 1717.00);
    account[16] = new Accounts ("Esmé Emem", 17, 1717.00);
    account[17] = new Accounts ("Ren Thoko", 18, 1818.00);
    account[18] = new Accounts ("Lei Yaroslava", 19, 1919.00);
    account[19] = new Accounts ("Xuân Seong-Hy", 20, 2020.00);
    account[20] = new Accounts ("Tu Maria", 21, 2121.00);
    account[21] = new Accounts ("Nasim Noor", 22, 2222.00);
    account[22] = new Accounts ("Chandra Morgan", 23, 2323.00);
    account[23] = new Accounts ("Camille Jie", 24, 2525.00);
    account[24] = new Accounts ("Adetokunbo Sam", 25, 2626.00);
    account[25] = new Accounts ("Makena Sothy", 26, 2726.00);
    account[26] = new Accounts ("Hanne Kit", 27, 2727.00);
    account[27] = new Accounts ("Almas Florence", 28, 2828.00);
    account[28] = new Accounts ("Yoshi Saša", 29, 2929.00);
    account[29] = new Accounts ("Cahyo Ime", 30, 3030.00);

    for (int i = 0; i <=29; i++)
        System.out.println(account[i]);
    System.out.println("Depositing $100.01 from every account and withdrawing $50.05 out of every account with fee");
    for (int i = 0; i <=29; i++){
        account[i].deposit (100.01);
        account[i].withdraw (50.05, 0.0);
    }
    System.out.println("After deposit and withdrawl");
    for (int i = 0; i <=29; i++)
        System.out.println(account[i]);
    System.out.println("Account number 30 will make invalid transactions...");

    account[29].deposit (-1000.00);
    account[29].withdraw (9999999999.00, 0.1);
    account[29].toString();

    System.out.println("Adding 3 percent interest to all accounts.");
    //account.addInterestAll(account);
}
}
```

In conclusion, I am not sure of how to make a method on adding interest to every account in the array. Thank you in advance

Comment: Pass the array to a method that iterates and updates. There will be a discussion around whether or not you should return a *new* array, bit that's a separate issue. What specific problem are you having with doing the first, easy option?

Comment: It looks like you have the right idea in your code: the last line is `account.addInterestAll(account);`, which you've commented out for reasons unknown.  This is exactly what you want - you just need to update your method to accept `account` as an argument.

Comment: @Zexus how do I have the method accept `account` as an argument?

Comment: Declare the method as `public double addInterestAll(Accounts[] account)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to follow the same pattern as

```
for (int i = 0; i <=29; i++){
    account[i].deposit (100.01);
    account[i].withdraw (50.05, 0.0);
}
```

like

```
for (int i = 0; i <=29; i++){
    account[i].addInterest ();
}
```

If you want one method to do all try

```
static public double addInterestAll (Accounts[] accounts)

   double balance = 0.0;
   for (int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++){
       balance += accounts[i].addInterest();
   }
   return balance;
}
```

Then call this code

```
double newBalance = addInterestAll (account);
```

Comment: yeah but I have to make a method and the account[i] is not declared in my class.

Comment: Alright I used your code, however in my main method I used `account.addInterestAll(account);` and it says "can not find symbol method addInterestAll(Accounts[])

Comment: does your method look like `static public double addInterestAll (Account[] accounts)` ?  BTW, this is not a very nice way to do it.  Personally I would have the method in the `SixSix` class **NOT** the `Accounts` class

Comment: no because my constructor is called `Accounts[]` with an "s" at the end. So at the top of my class i added `public Accounts[] account;` and replaced it in the parameter. But I am still getting errors. Also, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I also prefer the method in the main method as well. My assignment says "...provide a method to add 3 percent interest to all accounts whenever the method is invoked" So I assumed that I had to make the method but I don't know. Thank you for taking note of this.

Comment: do u think that I don't have to make a method in the class, according to what my assignment says?

Comment: I have fixed my code so that it is now `static public double addInterestAll (Accounts[] accounts)`  although this is bad naming as the class refers to just one Account.  If the assignment says make a method, then I would put this method in the `SixSix` class as it is working on the collection/Array